# Write a query to find students who take CS220 and no other courses

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM students s, student_enrollment se
WHERE s.student_no = se.student_no
AND s.student_no NOT IN ( SELECT student_no
                          FROM student_enrollment
                          WHERE course_no != 'CS220')
```

This is the solution.
the way i think is

```sql
AND s.student_no NOT IN ( SELECT student_no
                          FROM student_enrollment
                          WHERE course_no != 'CS220')
```

would show who takes only takes cs220 and along with other classes.
Not just showing the students who only take cs220.

thats why i dont understand why the solution is like this

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (I.e. [mcve].)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "except" operator. This will return students who took CS220 only. This will work as long as you have a clean students table.

```
    select distinct s.*
    from students s
    join student_enrollment se 
        on se.student_id = s.student_id
    where se.course_no = 'CS220'
    except 
    select distinct s.*
    from students s
    join student_enrollment se 
        on se.student_id = s.student_id
    where se.course_no <> 'CS220'
```